# Nginx location directive cannot be accessed

Tags: node.js, nginx

When Im trying to run the below nginx config file, I get error Cannot GET /index on using `http://domain_name/index`. When I hit `http://domain_name`, its calling 127.0.0.1/3000. What Im doing wrong here. Any help on this will be really helpful.

```
error_log  /tmp/logs/error.log;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  access_log  /tmp/logs/access.log;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  # BELOW IS THE PART TO PROXY MY samp1.js and samp2.js APP

  upstream first_entry {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
   upstream second_entry {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://first_entry;
    }
    location /index {
      proxy_pass http://second_entry;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does the URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000` work by it self ?

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady Yes its working

Answer (score 0):

Extend your server block with the directive `error_log /path/to/log/files/debug.log;` and `rewrite_log on;`. Then `tail -f /path/to/log/files/debug.log` and enter `http://domain_name/index` in your browser. You can now see live what nginx is doing while resolving the input URL. This should help you debugging the issue.

Please post the output of this in your question for further help and let me know if I can be of further assistance.